# Design pattern: Save private members

Tags: c#, database, design-patterns

Say we have a class Potato (and instances therefore) that has an attribute smoothness which is used for other method but is not pretended to be public. This attribute is setted when the instance is created and is used only internally the instance.

Moreover, my system should support several database drivers, therefore I have an interface "databse adaptor" that will be instantiated with the class which uses the driver I want to use at the moment.

Now comes the problem. I need to make the object(the potato) persistent and save it into a database, therefore I should save the smoothness of our potato by using the database adaptor class, but.. it's private!
How can I send the smoothness of the potato without making it accessible for other purposes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the smoothness attribute determined?  If it's derived from other properties, then there's no need to store it.  If it isn't, then where does it come from?

Comment: Have you thought about using a private setter? This way, smoothness cannot be set by anyone outside of the instance but can be retrieved. Any class, including your database adapter will need to read this value to be able to write to the database.

Comment: The smoothness is not derived it's just setted when the instance is created through the constructor and I would like it to be private for everyone but the database adaptor. I know it's quite weird and I'm not sure whether it is possible.

Comment: If the adaptor and potato are in the same assembly you could mark the Smoothness property as internal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a method that allows the object to save itself, taking a writer of some kind as a parameter. Since this is a database, you might need to have both Insert and Update methods, instead of just a Save method. You might put these into an interface as well.

rough example:

```
public interface IDatabaseSaveable
{
   void InsertToDatabase(Database pDatabase);
   void UpdateDatabase(Database pDatabase);
}

public class Potato : IDatabaseSaveable
{
   private int mID;
   private double mSmoothness;

   public void InsertToDatabase(Database pDatabase)
   {
      pDatabase.InsertToPotatoes(mID, mSmoothness, ...);
   }

   public void UpdateDatabase(Database pDatabase)
   {
      pDatabase.UpdatePotatoes(mID, mSmoothness, ...);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an importer/exporter interface pair that externalize the "state" of the `Potato` without giving access to its implementation details (in this case, its private members and data types). They are types of builders.

```
public class Potato {
  public interface IExporter {
    void AddSmoothness(string value);
  }
  public interface IImporter {
    string ProvideSmoothness();
  }

  public Potato(IImporter importer) {
    this.smoothness = int.Parse(importer.ProvideSmoothness());
  }

  public void Export(IExporter exporter) {
    exporter.AddSmoothness(this.smoothness.ToString());
  }

  public Potato(int smoothness) {
    this.smoothness = smoothness;
  }

  private int smoothness;
}
```

Then, your database adapter classes will implement the relevant interfaces and use the corresponding methods. Look [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2004/jw-0102-toolbox.html) for the original idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on having a smoothness property marked as `internal`. Assuming that potato must have a `smoothness` set before you can use it, an internal constructor might be better. I'm going to accept on faith that there's a good reason to hide smoothness. Modesty on the part of the potato, perhaps?

```
public class Potato
{
    internal int Smoothness { get; set; }

    internal Potato(int smoothness)
    {
        this.Smoothness = smoothness;
    }
    private Potato() { }
}
```

Only classes in the same assembly will be able to instantiate a `Potato` using the internal constructor. And only classes in the same assembly will be able to access Smoothness (so they can save the potato.)